# Why does Code Igniter file upload tutorial not work?

Tags: upload, codeigniter-3

I am doing the [code igniter file upload demo](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) but it doesn't work. When I try to upload the file I get the following error message:

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://[::1]/ul_ex/index.php/upload/do_upload
The system returned: (111) Connection refused
```

Clearly there's a problem with my path but I don't understand what is going wrong. I even copied and pasted the code just to make sure it wasn't a typo but it still doesn't work!

Do I need to update my routes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

OK, I overlooked a pretty simple thing which was I didn't set a base path in my config file. I set the project up quickly to test uploading but forgot about this. No problems now!